# how to get ip address inside cors Dynamic Origin?

Tags: node.js, cors

I build restAPI with nodejs and I want to limit user access with whitelisted ip or domain, to do that I use [NPM's CORS package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuring-cors-w-dynamic-origin), but I cant get client ip address that access restAPI, so.. how to get the ip address?

here the code:

```
const whitelist = ['http://localhost', 'http://127.0.0.1']
const corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    console.log(whitelist.indexOf(origin))
    console.log(origin)
    // if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      if (whitelist.indexOf('127.0.0.1') !== -1 || !origin) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Your ip address is not whitelisted'))
    }
  },
  methods: ["GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "HEAD", "PATCH"],
  allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
  credentials: true
}
app.get('/v2/cors', Cors(corsOptions), (req, res) => {
    res.json({ msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a whitelisted domain.' })
})
```

Comment: Why not use a separate middleware that has access to the `req` argument so it can get the IP address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you want to provide access based on the IP address of the user and not based on the domain name(i.e origin). In the documentation of the package, they have mentioned using corsOptionsDelegate for this. Try this...

```
const whitelist = ['http://localhost', 'http://127.0.0.1']
var corsOptionsDelegate = function (req, callback) {
  const corsOptions = {
      methods: ["GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "HEAD", "PATCH"],
      allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
      credentials: true
  };

  const myIpAddress = req.connection.remoteAddress; // This is where you get the IP address from the request
  if (whitelist.indexOf(myIpAddress) !== -1) {
      corsOptions.origin = true
  } else {
      corsOptions.origin = false
  }
  callback(null, corsOptions);
}

app.get('/v2/cors', Cors(corsOptionsDelegate), (req, res) => {
  res.json({ msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a whitelisted domain.' })
})
```

Comment: For future readers, `req.connection` is deprecated in Node v13.x onward.  Instead, you should use `req.socket` (https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_connection)

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with a range of IPs or wild cards instead of specific individual IPs? E.g. `42.59.*.*`

Answer (score 0):

According to [Cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuring-cors-asynchronously) document: https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuring-cors-asynchronously

```
const whitelist = ['https://domain1.com', 'https://domain2.com']
const whitelistIp = ["116.208.110.107"];

const corsOptionsDelegate = function (req, callback) {
const ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;

let corsOptions;

if (whitelist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')) !== -1 || whitelistIp.indexOf(ip) !== -1) {
    corsOptions = { origin: true } // reflect (enable) the requested origin in the CORS response
} else {
    corsOptions = { origin: false } // disable CORS for this request
}
    callback(null, corsOptions) // callback expects two parameters: error and options
}

app.get('/v2/cors', Cors(corsOptionsDelegate), (req, res) => {
  res.json({ msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a whitelisted domain.' })
})
```